# Change python import name without changing code and file structure

Tags: python, import

I currently have a package A from someone else that uses an import syntax like import A in its code, e.g. A/B/C/xx.py.

What I want to do is to reference package A in my project X, forming a package structure X/A like this. However, I need to meet the following two requirements:

1. not modify a single line of code in A
2. import A is not valid anywhere else unless it is in package X.

I spent a few days looking for a workaround, but none of it worked. All methods that do not throw an error result in import A being available everywhere else.

Answer (score -1):

You could create a `my_requirements.py` file that does all imports leaving out `module_name` or again deleing `module_name` under the conditions that you demand. You would then just have to:

```
import my_requirements
```

Comment: None of what you're suggesting in this answer actually works. It doesn't prevent any of the stuff it's supposed to prevent. You even acknowledge that fact halfway through the answer: "Having said the above, there is nothing preventing another coder importing `module_name` elsewhere in the code."

Comment: Besides not preventing what it's supposed to prevent, `del sys.modules["module_name"]` also results in the creation of "evil twin" modules if some code later tries to `import module_name` after the deletion.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica,  thank you for both comments. i have removed the `del` suggestion and shortened the answer.